# Установить значение для SplitView.Pane в коде UWP

Tags: uwp

SplitView в общем случае имеет две панели Pane и Content, примерно так:

```
<SplitView>
  <SplitView.Pane>
    ...
  </SplitView.Pane>
   <SplitView.Content>
    ...
  </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

Возникла необходимость определить SplitView в коде.
Для Content вопросов не возникает, например так:

MySpliView.Content = MyListBox  и т.п.

Однако для Pane  такой номер не проходит:

MySpliView.Pane = MyListBox выдает ошибку параметра

Как установить значение Pane в коде?

Comment: Какую "ошибку параметра" выдаёт? Текст ошибки напиши в вопрос. У меня нормально устанавливается показанным в вопросе способом. Если только этот ListBox уже есть в логическом дереве, тогда да, второй раз его добавить ещё куда-то может не получиться.

Comment: Да там текста практически нет, ошибка параметра и все. Бывают такие, слабо обработанные ошибки. Второе добавление листбокса... да, должна быть ошибка, но в этом случае как раз обычно внятное пояснение. Тем не менее, спасибо за идею, попробую проверить.

Comment: Не до конца, но помогло. Ошибки теперь нет, но и в Pane пусто. Это уже другая проблема, RenderSize = 0x0. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Владимир, без кода этот вопрос не решить